# Getting all keys from NCache Server

Tags: asp.net, caching, ncache

We are thinking about to use NCache from alachisoft.

Does it have a method to get all keys and values ?

We are trying to understand how we can do it?

Redis has this kind of feature, does Ncache miss this feature ?

Answer (score 5):

Does it have a method to get all keys and values? The answer is `YESSS!`

There are two ways to do it.

1. NCache has a method `GetEnumerator()` which traverse through all keys present in cache.
2. NCache's Cache class is a key-value pair object, so you can loop through all keys using foreach loop like;

   ```
   foreach (string key in _cache) // _cache is an object of 'Cache' class.
   {
       object value = _cache.Get(key);
       // do whatever you want do further.....
   }
   ```

Regards....

Answer (score 2):

Try LINQ they have an example on the website:

http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/38sp3/Online-Help/Developing-with-NCache/NETProgrammerGuide/ClientSideAPI-Programming/Queries&LINQ/LINQ/NCache-LINQ.htm

Comment: Great link @WFB